# Displaying highest and lowest input

Tags: c++, loops

Hello I am trying to display the highest and lowest numbers with the input of -99 to break the loop and without displaying -99 as the lowest number. Any help would be great.

```
int number;
int largeNum = 0 ;
int smallNum = 0;

cout << "enter numbers" ;

do
{
cin >> number;

if ( number > largeNum)
    largeNum = number;

if ( number < largeNum)
    smallNum = number;

if (number < smallNum)
    smallNum = number;

} while (number != -99);



      cout << largeNum << endl;
      cout << smallNum << endl;
```

Comment: I won't give the code as this looks like homework. You can take a look at `break` statement of C++ to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
do {
    cin >> number;

    if ( number == -99 ) {
        break;
    }

    if ( number > largeNum)
        largeNum = number;

    if ( number < largeNum)
        smallNum = number;

    if (number < smallNum)
        smallNum = number;

} while ( true );
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting exact code for homework like questions.

Comment: Why do you assume that this was a homework? Its looks fairly trivial that the user might have been trying something on his own. Also if you look, I have only changed the place where the comparison was being carried out. The user has done almost everything on his own.

Comment: If it is homework, I'd still fail it for lacking proper validation of the input operation....

Answer (score 0):

**the better solution to the problem would be by using sorting:**

```
    void main()
    {
    int array[100],n;

    //get number of elements
    cout<<"Enter number of elements: ";
    cin>>n;

    //get elements
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
int temp;
    cout<<"Enter element to position "<<i<<" :";
    cin>>temp;
//to break at -99
    if(temp==-99)
    break;
    else
    array[i]=temp;

    }

    //sort the elements in ascending order
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    if(array[i]>array[i+1])
    {
    int temp = array[i];
    array[i] = array[i+1];
    array[i+1] = temp;
    }
    }

    //display smallesst and largest

    cout<<"Smallest: "<<array[0];
    cout<<"Largest: "<<array[n-1];
    }
```

Comment: This is actually a *worse* solution since it uses unnecessary storage, it runs slower, and because the number of inputs is limited it doesn't even solve the problem as stated.

Comment: I agree it isnt a optimized code. this is for the better understanding. Once you get to understand the principles you can always optimize.]

Comment: you can always combine the 2 for loops, etc to optimize. But that i would prefer to leave to the implementer